# specify files in resources folder in spring application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application, the code need to access a file under resources folder. here is my application.properties file:

```
cert.file=classpath:/resources/cert.p12
```

however it always complained:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:/resources/cert.p12 (No such file or directory)
```

I double checked folder 
my_project/target/classes
to make sure the file cert.p12 exits there.

and in the code I tried to access the file:

```
@Value("${cert.file}")
private String certFile;
....
@Bean
public Sender sender() {
    return new Sender(certFile);
}
```

what exactly is the this classpath? and why it cannot find the file? Thanks!

Comment: have you managed to solve this?

Comment: is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 20):

Classpath includes what you have **inside** you resources dir.

Try:

```
cert.file=classpath:cert.p12
```

I'm assuming that you have standard maven catalog structure.

Comment: its threw the same error: FileNotFoundException: classpath:cert_key.p12.I use standard maven structure

Answer (score 10):

This syntax doesn't work with a normal FileInputStream. Use the Spring Resourceloader instead.

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

@Value("${property.name}")
private String property;

File getPropertyFile(){
    return resourceLoader.getResource(property).getFile();
}
```

*application.properties*

```
property.name=classpath:filename.txt
```

Comment: when i run app with `java -jar` this code is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `XXX.class.getResourceAsStream("filename")` to get a resource.
such as:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE));
        Key key = (Key) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
```

And, this is work in my code.The MyClass is the class witch use your crt file. My `PUBLIC_KEY_FILE` is `"/rsa/PublicKey"` and just store at the `src/main/resources/rsa` folder

[image: resources location]

Answer (score 0):

as @BeeNoisy said, you should use `getResourceAsSreame(...)` instead of `getResource(...).getFile()`.

i see exactly your problem and my code ran in my computer correctly but when i load app with embedded tomcat with `java -jar` command i see this error:

so i change code like this and error resolved:

```
private final String licencePass;
private final String licenceName;

public ProcessFormController(@Value("${ramona.licence.keystore.fullname}") String licenceName,
                             @Value("${ramona.licence.pass}") String licencePass) throws Exception {
    this.licenceName = licenceName;
    this.licencePass = licencePass;
    this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getHttpsRequestFactory());
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory getHttpsRequestFactory() throws Exception {
    logger.info("licenceName:" + licenceName);
    final InputStream resourceAsStream =
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                    licenceName
            );
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(resourceAsStream, licencePass.toCharArray());
    ...
}
```

properties:

```
ramona.licence.keystore.fullname=key.p12
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my experience

Step 1 : Create your resource file lets say under /src/main/resources/data/test.data 
Step 2 : Define the value in `application.properties/yml`

```
com.test.package.data=#{new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource("/data/test.data").getFile().getAbsolutePath()}
```

Step 3 : Get the file in your code

```
@Value("${com.test.package.data}")
private String dataFile;

private void readResourceFile() {
   Path path = Paths.get(dataFile);
   List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(path);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This path worked for me
cert.file=./build/resources/main/cert.p12